# element linkXRef is not allowed intelij maven

Tags: maven

I'm using IntelliJ version 2021.3.1. In in of my pom.xml I'm getting error message
Element linkXRef is not allowed here.

Here is my pom.xml looks like:

```
    <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <targetJdk>1.8</targetJdk>
       <rulesets>
            <ruleset>../favorites.xml</ruleset>
          </rulesets>
          <linkXref>true</linkXref>
          <format>xml</format>
          <aggregate>true</aggregate>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <includeTests>false</includeTests>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/generated/*.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Is there a work around for this on Intellij? It is legacy code and I do not want to remove it.

Comment: Which version of maven-pmd-plugin are you using?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

The parameter should be written with a capital R and a capital X.  You mistakenly typed a lowercase R.  Although this may be legacy code, when experiencing errors on a particular parameter it is a good idea to delete it and use the IDE to autocomplete/select the parameter name.

Solution:
linkXRef instead of linkXref